# Cython references to slots in a numpy array

Tags: numpy, pointers, reference, cython

I have an object with a numpy array instance variable.

Within a function, I want to declare local references to slots within that numpy array.

E.g.,

```
cdef double& x1 = self.array[0]
```

Reason being, I don't want to spend time instantiating new variables and copying values.

Obviously the above code doesn't work.  Something about c++ style references not supported.  How do I do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ references aren't supported as local variables (even in Cython's C++ mode) because they need to be initialized upon creation and Cython prefers to generate code like:

```
# start of function
double& x_ref
# ...
x_ref = something # assign
# ...
```

This ensures that variable scope behaves in a "Python way" rather than a "C++ way". It does mean everything needs to be default constructable though.

---

However, C++ references are usually implemented in terms of pointers, so the solution is just to use pointers yourself:

```
cdef double* x1 = &self.array[1]
x1[0] = 2 # use [0] to dereference pointer
```

Obviously C++ references make the syntax nicer (you don't have to worry about dereferences and getting addresses) but performance-wise it should be the same.